# Retrieving names from 2 tables with same column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to databases and i really stuck! Please give me a hand! Have no idea, where I made a mistake...

I have 2 tables patient and caretaker

they both have lastname and firstname

I need to retrieve lastname and firstname from both of them and i made the following query:

SELECT  firstname
FROM `mortenu8`.`patient`, `caretaker`
where caretaker.firstname = patient.firstname;

But it says 
Error Code: 1052. Column 'firstname' in field list is ambiguous 0.034 sec

Do you have any idea why? I will really appreciate your help...
Thanks!

Comment: you should specift which firstname

Comment: Is `mortenu8.patient` the name of your table?

Comment: patient is a name of my table

Comment: here is a script to my database... but it does not work... listed queries simply do not want to get listed

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mortenu8`.`caretaker` (
  `caretakerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` DECIMAL(10,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`caretakerID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mortenu8`.`patient` (
  `patientID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ssn` DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `age` INT(3) NOT NULL,
  `gender` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `caretakerid` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`patientID`),
  INDEX `caretakerid` (`caretakerid` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `caretakerid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`caretakerid`)
    REFERENCES `mortenu8`.`caretaker` (`caretakerID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Database Objects.

When you specify the firstname in the columns list where both the tables have the same column name, data base engine cannot recognize the first name of which table exactly are you trying to retrieve!!

Many of the above answers says the same thing.

Just to reiterate the same,

```
SELECT patient.firstname, ctaker.firstname 
FROM mortenu8.patient patient, caretaker ctaker 
WHERE ctaker.firstname = patient.firstname;
```

Comment: something in my  database is wrong... it lists 2 columns. Both columns list first names

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query of join is working you can try this

```
SELECT patient.firstname,caretaker.firstname
FROM mortenu8.patient, caretaker
where caretaker.firstname = patient.firstname
```

OR

```
SELECT caretaker.firstname
    FROM mortenu8.patient, caretaker
    where caretaker.firstname = patient.firstname
```

Comment: @user2986531 you can choose either 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT MP.firstname as PatientName,  
        C.firstname as CaretakerName
FROM mortenu8.patient MP, caretaker C 
where C.firstname = MP.firstname;
```

Comment: it also lists caretaker name 2 times

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT patient.firstname     
FROM mortenu8.patient, caretaker    
where caretaker.firstname = patient.firstname;
```

Comment: and this query lists name of caretaker once